# Is there any way to pull an image from private registry and cut URL?

Tags: docker, pull

I have some private Docker registry: http://some-registry-somewhere.com:5000.

When I need to run my compose configuration, I need to pull a target image.

```
$ docker pull some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1
```

In `docker-compose.yml` file, I have to set the same full URL-path because there is pulled image `some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1`.

To have an image with image name only we may tag it:

```
$ docker tag some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1 target/image:tag1
```

But is there any way to automatically cut Docker registry URL through Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way, because of API specification. The image name is not just the tag, it also identifies for docker engine, which registry should be used for pushes and pulls of this image.

While the first `some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1` is image `target/image:tag1` which is located in `some-registry-somewhere.com:5000`.

The second one `target/image:tag1` is, in other words, image, `docker.io/target/image:tag1`, which is located in official repository.

In fact, they can be different in most of the cases.

The one way, *which is not good, actually, because can be confusing (see again about repositories)*, is to use `&&`:

`docker pull some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1 && docker tag some-registry-somewhere.com:5000/target/image:tag1 target/image:tag1`